# Is (0,0,0) an undefined vector?

Tags: vectors

I'm not sure what to make of the direction of a vector with components (0,0,0). Is it an undefined vector?

Comment: Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_vector

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with a vector having all zero components. But a vector like that does have an undefined *direction*. So the definition of a vector as "something which has a magnitude and a direction" can throw you off here a little.

Answer (score 6):

In mathematics that is the identity element **0** for vector addition, and is a key object in the definition of a [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space).

Physically, if $(0, 0, 0)$ is the position vector of some particle, then that just means it is located at the origin.